# How to Edit Bookmarks in a Word Document using Universal Windows App

Tags: uwp, .net-core, ms-word, office-interop, windows-10-universal

I am building a Universal Windows application(UWP) which need to the add text to the bookmarks in a Microsoft Word Document.

I added the library Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and included the below code that can add text to the bookmarks:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc;

object oTemplate = filepath;

oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

oDoc.Bookmarks["BookmarkName"].Range.Text = "BookmarkText";
```

Error Message:

> System.IO.FileLoadException
>     HResult=0x80131515
>     Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
>     Source=BuyOutApp
>     StackTrace:
>      at BuyOutApp.DocumentsGenerated.TemplateRFQs.GenerateBearingPadRFQ() in C:\Users\s.raja\Source\Workspaces\Workspace2\Buyout Application\BuyOutAppSln\BuyOutApp\DocumentsGenerated\TemplateRFQs.cs:line 43
>      at BuyOutApp.Views.OutputShellPage.BtnSubmit_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\s.raja\Source\Workspaces\Workspace2\Buyout Application\BuyOutAppSln\BuyOutApp\Views\OutputShellPage.xaml.cs:line 239
>   Inner Exception 1:
>   NotSupportedException: A Primary Interop Assembly is not supported in AppX.

Comment: UWP cannot directly use office interop word API. But you can use desktop bridge way to use your UWP app as entry point and then call desktop extension. You can see stefan's [blog](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/) for details